# CF Express to SD card adapter

Tags: sd

Rather noob question here. I am wondering how large is the actual hardware for the SD native host interface. Would the hardware fit in the XQD or CF Express card form factor (in addition to the SD card or micro SD card itself) and if so would an adapter then be possible that would allow a CF Express slot to accept an SD card?

TIA.

Comment: If someone isn't already selling it then probably not.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering how large is the actual hardware for the SD native host interface.

A couple hundred macrocells, SD is not that complex hardware-wise.

> a CF Express slot to accept an SD card

I have no idea about the form factor of these, but cf express is just PCIe, and SD card readers with PCIe interface exist, and the ICs are tiny.

Note that a device that is equipped with the relatively expensive CF express B interface probably needs data rates that an SD card simply could not offer, so I have my doubts regarding the utility of your idea.

Devices that could indeed work with both SD card or CF express speeds will have the CF express type A interface, which is designed to allow both SD card or CF Express cards.